# When using MyFaces 2.1, with Eclipse Juno, how do I get rid of a space after the doctype

Tags: jsf, whitespace, facelets, doctype, myfaces

I have searched all around for an answer, and tried many things, but no luck. When I use MyFaces 2.1 with Eclipse Juno, and attempt to create an HTML5 page, I get

> ```
> <!DOCTYTPE html >
> ```

Notice the space after the "html". When this page is viewed in FireFox, using HTML Tidy, it throws an error saying its an invalid doctype.

The source xhtml file contains  with no space. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Which MyFaces implementation version exactly? "2.1" is merely a spec version. The newest MyFaces 2.1 implementation version is currently 2.1.10. Are you using that version? By the way, I don't see it with Mojarra 2.1.17 --I use HTML5 doctype all the time-- and I don't believe that Eclipse could be causing this in any way.

Comment: I was in MyFaces 2.1.9. I will try the latest version today. Thats whats strange, nothing should be adding the space. I have tried hundreds of things, but to no avail. The page displays ok, its just that I get those validation errors.

Comment: JSF parses Facelets files into a XML tree, builds the JSF component tree based on it which in turn ultimately generates HTML. So it isn't exactly emitting Facelets files literally :) In any case, I was able to reproduce your problem with MyFaces 2.1.9 and also 2.1.10. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce it in at least MyFaces 2.1.9 and 2.1.10 (didn't tried older versions). This problem doesn't manifest in Mojarra. It's undoubtedly a bug in MyFaces. I recommend to [report it to MyFaces guys](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES).

For the meantime until they get it fixed, I found a workaround. Replace `<!DOCTYPE>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    ...
</html>
```

by [`<h:doctype>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/doctype.html)

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <h:doctype rootElement="html" />
    <html lang="en">
        ...
    </html>
</ui:composition>
```

Its renderer generates the proper space-less doctype.

This problem is in no way related to Eclipse. It's just a tool like Notepad.

Comment: Thank you, That workaround worked. I will report it to MyFaces team.